# Pyside window closes immediately after opening

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I've been able to create pyside UIs before using this method, but for some reason for this time it wont stay open. It seems to flicker on quickly and then closes. I believe that it would be the trash colector that delets the app for not being used but I'm not sure as to how I can use the app more.

```
# coding: iso8859-1
import locale
import views
from PySide import QtGui
import PySide
from PySide import QtCore
import sys

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, '')
class gui(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__()
        print "inside __init__"
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.menuBTN = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.menuBTN.setText("MENU")
        self.menuBTN.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.grid.addWidget(self.menuBTN, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setWindowTitle('Office Works')
        self.showFullScreen()

    def change_layout(self):
        '''
        Method for saving the current view class and
        loading the view requested by the user. this
        method can be called by any of the view classes
        and it's functions to be able to change the screen
        when the user clicks on any if it's list objects or
        buttons

        '''
        pass
        blah=()
        class_temp = views.billing(blah)
        self.grid.addLayout(class_temp.grid, 0, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui()
    print "executed gui"
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: My views class is will only be used in the change layout method whihc is never called. I don't believe that that would be the problem, however I did try to execute the program without the views import and it has the same results.

Comment: change `gui()`  to `my_variable_that_does_not_get_garbage_collected = gui()`

Comment: Amazing. so simple. muched obliged! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't set any variable to the gui.

```
window = gui()
window.show()
```

Typically you want the main window as the main object. So gui might want to inherit QMainWindow.

```
class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()

        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        ...
```

Another thing you can do is to add all of the items to the layout and simply hide/show the ones you want to use. This might be easier than creating another view when a button is clicked.